Angular "No native build was found" error in new project (Windows, Node.js 20.14.0)
I'm trying to run a new Angular project but encountering the error "No native build was found" when I execute ng serve. I've created a fresh project using npx @angular/cli new admin-angular and haven't added any custom dependencies yet.

Upgraded npm to the latest version (currently npm 10.8.1).
Reinstalled project dependencies using npm uninstall && npm install.
Checked for compatibility of any native addons (only lmdb shows up in node_modules).
(If applicable) Verified custom build processes (mention if your project has any)


Faced similar problem but on Debian. You can use node-gyp in order to compile it yourself. You may need to install dependencies first (explained in the README) and then install it through NPM. Once done, move to node_modules/addon_that_gives_u_error then node-gyp configure and node-gyp build. Move to project root and ng serve.
